# distorted information in the client side

Tags: processing

I am trying to build a simple server - client code, where the server sends information and the client reads it. However if I send an `int` bigger then `255`, the `int` comes to the client distorted

The server code:

```java
import processing.net.*;
Server myServer;

void setup() {

  size(300, 250);
  myServer = new Server(this, 5204);


}

void keyPressed()
{
  myServer.write(2221);
}
void draw()
{

}
```

The client Code:

```java
import processing.net.*; 
Client myClient; 
int dataIn = 0;

void setup() {

  size(300, 250);
  myClient = new Client(this, "127.0.0.1", 5204);


}

void draw() {
  if (myClient.available() > 0) { 
    dataIn = myClient.read();
    println(dataIn);
  }

}
```

Below is what is printed client side:

```java
173
```

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

The `read()` function gives you individual bytes, each between `0` and `255`. If you want to use the `read()` function, then you'll have to combine the bytes into the resulting data. How you do this depends on exactly what that data is.

You might also want to check out the `readString()` and the other read functions. More info can be found in [the reference](https://processing.org/reference/libraries/net/index.html).